# wrong classpath and parameters while running WebLogic in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, weblogic

I've installed and configured WebLogic and everything works when I run it from the console (it's WebLogic 10.3.5, with JDK 6, on Windows 7).

However, when I configure WebLogic in IntelliJ IDEA (correct BEA Home, correct domain path, etc.) and try to run it, it even uses the correct startWebLogic.cmd, but all I get as output is:

```
C:\Users\konradstrack\dev\weblogic\base_domain\startWebLogic.cmd
.
.
JAVA Memory arguments: -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=48m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
.
WLS Start Mode=Development
.
CLASSPATH=C:\PROGRA~2\Java\JDK16~1.0_2\lib\tools.jar;C:\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic_sp.jar;C:\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\modules\features\weblogic.server.modules_10.3.5.0.jar;C:\wlserver\server\lib\webservices.jar;C:\modules\org.apache.ant_1.7.1/lib/ant-all.jar;C:\modules\net.sf.antcontrib_1.1.0.0_1-0b2/lib/ant-contrib.jar;C:\wlserver\common\derby\lib\derbyclient.jar;C:\wlserver\server\lib\xqrl.jar
.
PATH=;C:\wlserver\server\native\win\32;C:\wlserver\server\bin;C:\modules\org.apache.ant_1.7.1\bin;C:\PROGRA~2\Java\JDK16~1.0_2\jre\bin;C:\PROGRA~2\Java\JDK16~1.0_2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.3\bin\..\.\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\program files (x86)\jetbrains\intellij idea 11.1.3\jre\jre\bin;C:\wlserver\server\native\win\32\oci920_8
.
***************************************************
*  To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *
*  password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *
*  server administration, use the WebLogic Server *
*  console at http:\\hostname:port\console        *
***************************************************
starting weblogic with Java version:
java version "1.6.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode, sharing)
Starting WLS with line:
C:\PROGRA~2\Java\JDK16~1.0_2\bin\java -client   -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=48m  -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=C:\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.policy  -Xverify:none  -da -Dplatform.home=C:\wlserver -Dwls.home=C:\wlserver\server -Dweblogic.home=C:\wlserver\server   -Dweblogic.management.discover=true  -Dwlw.iterativeDev= -Dwlw.testConsole= -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole=  weblogic.Server
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/Server
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.Server
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: weblogic.Server.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" Disconnected from server
```

All the paths in classpath and parameters such as `-Dplatform.home` are pointing to `C:\wlserver`, which is a completely wrong place (WebLogic is located in `C:\Users\konradstrack\dev\weblogic\weblogic-10.3.5`).

And my question is: why is it happening, and what can I do to overcome it and cause the IntelliJ IDEA - WebLogic combination to behave correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried setting `MW_HOME` value in the Windows Environment variables dialog? Because that might be the location where IntelliJ Idea reads WebLogic parameters and values.

This post might be useful for you: https://blogs.oracle.com/imc/entry/weblogic_12c_dev_install_mw

Comment: Cool, this actually solves the problem. Thank you :)
One important thing is that when someone chooses the 3rd solution from this post (which actually looks like the best option), the `stopWebLogic.cmd` also needs to be updated (`MW_HOME` is unset there too), in order to shutdown WebLogic seamlessly.

Comment: This isn't on windows alone, Mac is the same way - unless you explicitly pass the MW_HOME environment variable through the dialog box, it won't get picked up.  I had it set up in by .bash_profile, but it was not being detected by IntelliJ.

Answer (score 2):

That also happened to me on Mac OsX 10.7.5 with WebLogic wls1211_dev. Following the instructions in README.txt the server launched successfully. But when trying to launch it from IntelliJ  it was saying the same thing:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/Server
```

So I had to manually set the variable in all scripts in the mydomain directory (startWebLogic.sh, and all other launching/stoping scripts in the mydomain/bin ) :

```
export MW_HOME=/Users/mario/Programs/wls1211_dev
```

Comment: Thank you! I had this problem with OS X 10.9.1, Intelli J 13.0.2 and WebLogic 10.3.6.0. I had already configured the MW_HOME variable in the terminal, but this didn't help. After adding the export command as you said to the startWebLogic.sh script, I was finally able to run the server from IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

After running the ..\server\bin\setWLSEnv.cmd I was able to restart weblogic server.

This file sets the classpath and path values for system.